# Create clip mask image src with using html/css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image

I want to create image mask with using only html and css. Not using svg or background image.

The clip mask need to apply with `<img src='">`. I can't able to achieve this without background image.

```css
.pic-mask {
    position:relative;
}
.pic-mask:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(63, 72, 48, 0.8);
    -moz-transition: background .3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: background .3s linear;
    -ms-transition: background .3s linear;
    -o-transition: background .3s linear;
    transition: background .3s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="pic-mask">
<img src="https://im.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-1-1bf1c27255.jpg" width="500">
</div>
```

My expected output like below image

[image: I want to achieve like this]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the dynamic width and height of the image, try something like this:

Html:

```
<div class="image-container">
 <div class="pic-mask">
  <img src="https://im.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-1-1bf1c27255.jpg">
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-container img {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.pic-mask {
    position:relative;
}
.pic-mask:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(63, 72, 48, 0.8);
    -moz-transition: background .3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: background .3s linear;
    -ms-transition: background .3s linear;
    -o-transition: background .3s linear;
    transition: background .3s linear;
}
```

If you want to limit the width of the picture, you can do so on the image container by putting for example:

```
.image-container {
  max-width:500px;
}
```

The reason for it is pic-mask is absolute to relative parent element and right:0 will put it at 0px from the right of it's relative parent but the picture itself is set to smaller width than the parent element.

Comment: Sorry. Not as per my My expected. you check my above image output.

Comment: Which part of the behavior is not expected?

Comment: Do you mean the colors are different? You have to be specific about your problem, is it the background overlapping the image or is it that you can't match the color of the background?